# Как сделать форму с заменяющимися элементами?

Tags: c#, winforms

Дело обстоит так: делаю курсовую используя виндовс формы. Хочу сделать всю программу на одной форме, но имея на форме кнопки типа Назад/Далее, чтобы одни элемент исчезали, а другие появлялись вместо них. Есть мысль сделать это используя свойство видимости элементов, т.е. сначала одни элементы видны, нажимаю кнопку, например Далее, и эти элементы становятся невидимыми, а другие - наоборот. Собсна вопрос: есть ли способ реализовать мою задумку по проще?

Comment: `Panel` и несколько `UserControl`ов сменяющих друг друга.

Comment: Bulson, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, я решил использовать TabControl и не усложнять себе жизнь:)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/468001)

Comment: @Radzhab так это ответ автора самому себе